# Custom UITableViewCell overlapping objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom TableViewCell which contains the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MatchCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var blueTeamLogoImageView: UIView
    @IBOutlet var blueTeamNameShort: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var blueTeamScore: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var blueTeamStats: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var blueTeamWinIndicator: UIView


    @IBOutlet var redTeamLogoImageView: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet var redTeamNameShort: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var redTeamScore: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var redTeamStats: UILabel
    @IBOutlet var redTeamWinIndicator: UIView

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Now I try to add my MatchCell to my !GROUPED! (dont know if it makes any difference) UITableView. I've implemented:

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int

and added: tableView.dataSource = self
They are all returning the correct values, already checked that.

Now when I run my app... it looks like this: http://www1.xup.to/exec/ximg.php?fid=14474271

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ->     UITableViewCell! {
    if self.lcsWeek {

        let cell: MatchCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MatchCell

        var currentDay: Day = self.lcsWeek!.Days[self.lcsWeek!.getDayById(indexPath.section)]!
        var currentMatch: Match = currentDay.matches[indexPath.row]

        cell.blueTeamNameShort.text = currentMatch.blueTeamAcronym
        cell.redTeamNameShort.text = currentMatch.redTeamAcronym

        return cell
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

It should look like this: http://www1.xup.to/exec/ximg.php?fid=19982127

I think the problem is located somewhere in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function... I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Your table has no information, how big those cells should be.

Comment: It works like a charm now. Thank you so much! 

    tableView.delegate = self

and 
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat
 did the trick :D